# How to refactor this switch construction

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have generic service `IService<T>` and some implementation `ServiceA: IService<A>`, `ServiceB: IService<B>` that provides different types data `A` and `B`.
Depends on type I need to call appropriate service, get data from service , check for null and map to type `IWidget`. Also, i have extension methods for mapping each type, for example

```
   public static class Mapper 
   {
      public static IWidget Map(this A data)
      { 
          return new WidgetA{......};
      }
      public static IWidget Map(this B data)....
   }
```

Because of after GetData I get unknow type, I can't to call apropriate mapping. How can i refactor  this construction

```
        IWidget widget;
        switch (currentItem.Type)
        {
            case "A":
                {
                    var data = ServiceA.GetData(ProductAlias);
                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        return EmptyContent;
                    }
                    widget = data.Map();
                    break;
                };
            case "B":
                {
                    var data = ServiceB.GetData(ProductAlias);
                    if (data == null)
                    {
                        return EmptyContent;
                    }
                    widget = data.Map();
                    break;
                };
        }
```

I would like to get somthing like this

```
        object data = currentItem.Type switch
        {
            "A" => ServiceA.GetData(),
            "B" => ServiceB.GetData(),
            _ => null
        };
        if (data == null)
        {
            return EmptyContent;
        }

        var widget = data.Map();  - Mapping can't be called from Object type
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map` cannot be called because it doesn't belong to `object`.

Maybe `object data = ...` should have a different type or maybe an `interface`?

```
IMyType data = currentItem.Type switch
```

Or, maybe you can cast data, as in:

```
var widget = ((MyTypeWithMapFunction)data).Map();
```

Comment: I can't link types `A` and `B` in general interface or type. It are two differents types. Because of this, I can`t cast to general type and use unified mapper

Comment: Maybe consider refactoring into a generic where `GetData()` becomes `GetData<T>()`

Comment: Originally, `GetData<T>` was generic, i simplified it in message. But, what does changes if `GetData()` becomes generic?  `GetData<A>`  returns type `A`  `GetData<B>` returns type `B`